# Lockdown failed: TypeError: At intrinsics.Object.groupBy expected boolean not function

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

lockdown-run.js:17 Lockdown failed:
TypeError: At intrinsics.Object.groupBy expected boolean not function

lockdown-more.js:99 Protecting intrinsics failed:
ReferenceError: harden is not defined
(anonymous) @ lockdown-more.js:99

I tried to solve this issue but didn't get any answer.

Comment: issue: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/20937 i was able to reproduce

Comment: In my case, updating Metamask extension to the last version (11.1.1) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 123):

It's just an chrome extension which is causing this error. Try disabling your chrome extensions. In my case it was MetaMask extension.

Comment: But MetaMaks is essential, there is no way to fix this issue in other way?

Answer (score 15):

If you have metamask installed it's probably the culprit.

Just go to chrome://extensions/?id=nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn and click update...

Answer (score 3):

If you are not sure which extension is causing the issue, try running the local server in a **Private window** (e.g.: Incognito mode in Chrome). Since, extensions are by default disabled in private mode.

Answer (score 0):

In my case MetaMask extension is causing it, so just go to,

`chrome://extensions/?id=nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn`

and select `Site access` => `On click` option, this solved the issue for me.

[image]